# Maze generator removes previous path and only displays current one

Tags: vb.net

I am making a maze generator on vb.net. A fullstop (.) represents a path, and a hashtag (#) represents a wall. My code prints each path, but removes the previous path at the same time. I would like it to keep the previous paths so that it can make a complete maze. Here is a screenshot showing what I mean: http://prntscr.com/jhsyox

Comment: " I haven't added validation yet" What would you be validating? I didn't see any user input. If there is an index out of range it needs to be fixed not validated.

Comment: In your `UpdateGrid` method, you have this inside your loop:  `grid(i, j) = "#"`.  Since you loop through the entire grid, every location gets overwritten with a #.  I think you just need to remove that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DrawFirstGrid, don't print "#"

```
grid(i, j) = "#"
Console.Write(grid(i, j))
```

In UpdateGrid, you delete everything you previously did and print the previous value.

```
Sub UpdateGrid(ByVal newX, ByVal newY) 'refresh grid when changes are made

    grid(newX, newY) = "."

    For i = 0 To maxColumn
        For j = 0 To maxRow
            Console.Write(grid(i, j))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next

End Sub
```

Now, you should notice that DrawFirstGrid and UpdateGrid has something similar. You could remove the drawing logic out and have a DrawGrid instead.

The directions array is useless and CreatePassage will be called forever.

Comment: Why is the direction array useless? I used it so that I can determine the direction of the maze. Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: @person your direction array contains the number 0 to 3 at index 0 to 3. When your random returns 2, you go in the direction array at index 2 and get the number 2.